# Android YouTubePlayer make loop

Tags: android, android-youtube-api

Is it possible to setup new [YouTubePlayer for Android](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/) to make it play video in loop (repeatedly)?

I haven't found yet such methods in [docs](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/reference/com/google/android/youtube/player/YouTubePlayer).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could attach a `YouTubePlayer.PlayerStateChangeListener` then start the video over in [`onVideoEnded`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/reference/com/google/android/youtube/player/YouTubePlayer.PlayerStateChangeListener#onVideoEnded()).

To restart the video, call this method - 
`youTubePlayer.seekToMillis(0)` in `onVideoEnded()`.

Comment: Is it possible to play video in playlist it randomly